# Handling Dynamic Properties for a class in c++

Tags: c++, class, dynamic

I have a container class, lets call it TestClass and a general property class, Property.

Now what I need to do is allow different instances of the TestClass to have a multiple "Properties". These properties will be added dynamically and new ones could be defined during runtime.

The naive way of handling this appears to simply have something like a vector that stores the various instances of the Property class.

```
class TestClass{
   public:
      std::vector<Property> properties ;
      addProperty(Property newProperty) {....}
      getProperty(String name) {....}
} ;

class Property{
 String name ;
 double value ;
 Definition definition ;
 ....
};

class Definition {
 ....
} ;
```

However, what I need to do in other part of my program is have an efficient way to say getPropertyValue("X") from TestClass...first check that it is an existing property and then retrieve the value of the property....as well as a variety of other operations.

Using the naive approach, would result in a very inefficient method for checking for a particular property (at a guess based on property name).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) using the name of the property as a key and the property as a value. very similar to your naive approach, but much faster.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a map or other associative array container.  Something like:

```
class TestClass{
   public:
      std::map<string, double> properties ;
      ....
```

Will allow you to efficiently check for existing properties.

Comment: Unfortunately, the property class will be more complex than just a name and a value.